# What's the meaning of the question mark inside the angle brackets: <? extends java.lang.Comparable>

Tags: java, google-app-engine

In App Engine, according to [the JavaDoc](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/DataTypeTranslator.html), the `getTypeRank` method has this signature:

```
public static int getTypeRank(java.lang.Class<? extends java.lang.Comparable> datastoreType)
```

In the method signature there is a question mark inside the angle brackets:

**`<? extends java.lang.Comparable>`**

What does it signify?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`?` essentially indicates a wildcard.  `<? extends java.lang.Comparable>` means "any type that extends java.lang.Comparable (or Comparable itself) can be used here".

Answer (score 6):

It's called **bounded wildcard**

`<? extends Comparable>` is an example of a bounded wildcard. The ? stands for an unknown type, just like the wildcards we saw earlier. However, in this case, we know that this unknown type is in fact a subtype of Comparable. (Note: It could be Comparableitself, or some subclass; it need not literally extend Comparable.)

More details you find [here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html)

Answer (score 2):

It means "any class that implements the `Comparable` interface. Thus, a call would e.g. look like `getTypeRank(String.class)`.

Answer (score 1):

? refers to any subclass of java.lang.Comparable.  In other words, any class that extends java.lang.Comparable.